# How to setup audio stream offset

Tags: javascript, actions-on-google

I build an action which plays some audio file. I want to add ability for user to listen from the place he stopped. In Alexa there is an `offset` parameter which I could specify. Is there anything similar for Google Assistant?

For now I start playback like that:

```
conv.ask(new MediaObject({
  name: 'some file',
  contentUrl: AudioFileUrlProvider.generateTempUrl(),
  description: 'some description',
}));
```

I know about [MediaObject](https://actions-on-google.github.io/actions-on-google-nodejs/classes/conversation_response.mediaobject.html) but there is no parameter to specify offset.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately there isn't currently a way to specify an offset to the media object.

Comment: Taking into account all the powerfulness of Dialogflow it's really pity to see such obvious features missing in other Actions SDK.